# how to move a button to left or right programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to animate a button by getting its co-ordinates and then increasing or decreasing them one by one so that the button can go to left and then come to the right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a TranslateAnimation:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y);
animation.setDuration(1000); // duartion in ms
animation.setFillAfter(false);
button.startAnimation(animation);
```

I'm not sure how you can get it's position, button.getTop() and button.getLeft() could work...

Comment: I don't know why but button.getTop() and button.getLeft() both gives the value 0.

Comment: Thank you @D-32 TranslateAnimation works absolutely fine button is moving.

Comment: Can you put your xml with the button into your question?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help you but i was struck with the same problem i was able to do this using these methods, setTranslationX(float) setTranslationY(float)

you can use it Like this

```
Button button = (button) findViewById(your id); 
button.setTranslationX(a float value);
```

here's the android documentation that provide more information [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:translationX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atranslationX)

Answer (score 1):

```
   Solution for those who are looking for left to right animation)

            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1500.0f); // new TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta,float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)

               animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
                animation.setRepeatCount(1); // animation repeat count
            animation.setFillAfter(false);
                your_view .startAnimation(animation);//your_view for mine is imageView     


Solution for those who are looking for repeated animation(for eg. left to right and right to left)

            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1500.0f); // new TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta,float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
                animation.setDuration(1500); // animation duration
                animation.setRepeatCount(4); // animation repeat count
                animation.setRepeatMode(2); // repeat animation (left to right, right to left)

                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                your_view .startAnimation(animation);//your_view for mine is imageView
```

Answer (score 1):

When button clicked image moves from left to right
you can use this code for fragments also.

insert this code in onCreateView for fragments or directly use button listener.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_move,container,false);
    mBtnMove = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
    mImageMove = view.findViewById(R.id.imv_move);
    mBtnMove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float start_x_axis = 0; // initialize the axis value start from and end
            float start_y_axis = 1000;
            float end_x_axis = 0;
            float end_y_axis = 0;
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(start_x_axis, start_y_axis, end_x_axis, end_y_axis);
            animation.setDuration(2500); // Duration of image to move from left to right
            mImageMove.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
  return view;
```